# Flutter: setState not updating UI

Tags: flutter

onTap it prints value but setState doesnt makes any difference in UI and im using it in a stateful widget and inside build too, i couldnt get where im making mistake, and im using flutter beta.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

String text = "HEY";

void bb(){
  print('Clicked Clicked');
  setState(() {
    text = "HEY2";
  });
}

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image:  DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/floor.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'HELLO, WORLD!', 
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), 
              textScaleFactor: 6,),
          ),
          Divider(height: 80),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              bb();
            },
            child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          ),

        ],),
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: yes sure here is the whole code @Uma 
https://del.dog/molerrobab.txt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your variable it's not part of the State of the page, its part of the build function. Everytime the state changes, the build function is triggered, changing back the value of the variable `text`.

You need to move this part:

```
  String text = "HEY";

    void bb(){
      print('Clicked Clicked');
      setState(() {
        text = "HEY2";
      });
    }
```

to outside the build function,  becoming something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    String text = "HEY";

    void bb(){
      print('Clicked Clicked');
      setState(() {
        text = "HEY2";
      });
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<bool> _selections = List.generate(3, (index) => false);
```

Comment: This line saved my day "Your variable it's not part of the State of the page, its part of the build function. Everytime the state changes, the build function is triggered, changing back the value of the variable"

Answer (score 3):

You should not put the variable inside the `build`. It should be outside the `build` function.

```
class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
    String text = "HEY";

    void bb() {
      print('Clicked Clicked');
      setState(() {
      text = "HEY2";
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple common mistake!
Good catch. Thanks for the answer